# Numpy: vectorize sum of lagged differences

Tags: python, numpy

Is it possible to compute the sum

[image]

with vector operations in numpy (*y* is an Tx1 vector), or do I have to do it with a loop? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by slicing the array:

```
import numpy as np
y = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
print np.sum(np.square(y[1:] - 2*y[:-1]))
# 14
```

where `y[1:]` means skipping the first element, and `y[:-1]` means skipping the last element.